# Data validation allows numbers and some strings?

Tags: excel, validation, vba

I want to do a data validation in BFF!range("A3:A40"). I want to only allow numbers from 0 to 24 and in the same time the list of strings "A" , "B", "C", "D". The list is present in Liste!range("C2:C100").

here is the code for the first part (list of strings), but i don't know how to add the second part (numbers between 0 and 24).

```
Sub Data_Validation_Nom()

'change Sheet1 to suit
Set wsListe = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Liste")
Set wsBFF = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("BFF")

Set range1 = wsListe.Range("C2:C100")
Set rng = wsBFF.Range("A3:A40")

With rng.Validation
    .Delete 'delete previous validation
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
        Formula1:="='" & wsListe.Name & "'!" & range1.Address

End With

End Sub
```

Can someone helps me please

Comment: so it can **only be** `A` or `B` or `C` or `D` or `any number from 0 to 24` or is it a combination of these? or are there more values ... I ask because C2:C100 is a lot more than a, b,c or d.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman I believe it is `A0,A1,A2...B0,B1,B2...,` which is 100 so there is one missing.